# scalacheck case class random data generator

Tags: scala, testing, scalacheck

I'm trying to generate random data with Scalacheck. I have a hierarchy of case classes with many properties. The only way I've found so far to populate the case classes is like this :

```
case class Data(a: String,
                b: String,
                c: String)

val genLigneDecompte: Gen[Data] = for {
  ag <- Gen.alphaStr
  bg <- Gen.alphaStr
  cg <- Gen.alphaStr
} yield Data(
    a = ag,
    b = bg,
    c = cg
  )
```

For a case class with 10-20 properties it's pretty tedious. I was wondering if there was a way to automate it somehow...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am sure somebody will come up with a solution that abstracts over arity using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless). But there are some helper methods to generate Gen[T] instances from functions of varying arity, which can be used with the apply method of the case class companion object

```
case class Data(a: String, b: String, c: String)

val dataArb = Arbitrary(Gen.resultOf(Data))
// equivalent to
// val f: (String, String, String) => Data = Data.apply
// val gen: Gen[Data] = Gen.resultOf(f)
// val arb: Arbitrary[Data] = Arbitrary(gen)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: There is, as in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33375918/333643 (https://github.com/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless)

Answer (score 12):

There is a shapeless based Scalacheck library https://github.com/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless what you might be looking for

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would be [**`DanielaSfregola/random-data-generator`**](https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/random-data-generator), A library to generate random data for test purposes, using [ScalaCheck](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck) and [scalacheck-shapeless](https://github.com/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless).

For Scala 2.11.8 or more, it can [generate for you the initialization sequence for a case class with many field](https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/random-data-generator/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/danielasfregola/randomdatagenerator/RandomDataGeneratorSpec.scala#L70-L120).